# Rails: Is it bad practice to handle CRUD operations for two models in one Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I am working on a Rails project. I was advised to make one controller, the Home_Controller, which would handle the requests of the site. I have two different models, Post and Person (which btw are totally independent). I would like to define methods like `new` in the Home Controller but it seems against convention to write controller methods like `new_person` and `new_post`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **IS** against the MVC pattern, as your `Home_Controller` should only control the `Home` model.

You should have a `PeopleController` and a `PostsController` to separate your concerns.

That being said - it's not totally unheard of to have the system that you are asking for.. You'll just have to create your own custom routes in `routes.rb` to match what you want.  For example, your HomeController could look like,

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new_person
    @person = Person.create
  end
  def new_post
    @post   = Post.create
  end
end
```

Routes would look something like,

```
get 'people/new' => 'home#new_person'
get 'post/new' => 'home#new_post'
```

the main issue is that when you stray away from this convention, you run into very unreadable and hard to maintain code.  especially when you have multiple hands in 1 file.

Answer (score 1):

Going to go ahead and say *probably*. It's hard to know exactly outside of context, but yes, this would go against convention.

Separate from the convention issue, is maintainability and readability and having one massive controller file would be hell to develop on.